# Why does this exception propagate all the way to App::fatal?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In this snippet the problem is that I'm saving $model which is null (thanks @Lucas Brito).
What I don't understand is:

1. Why the exception isn't caught in the try/catch that is around $model->save()
2. Why the $exception variable in the App::fatal is empty
3. How could I show a more explicit error

Every time I call `$model->save();`

```
$new = new System();
$new->imcid = $imcid;
$new->name = $name;
$new->validate();
Log::info('At update');
try{
    $model->save();
}catch(\Exception $e){
    Log::info('Exception thrown');
}
Log::info('Done');
```

In the log I can see the 'At update' but not 'Exception thrown' or 'Done'.
I get the message defined on routes.php

```
App::fatal(function($exception){
    return Response::json(array(
        'message' => 'damn...',
        'exception' => $exception
    ), 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exceptions were escalating all the way to fatal because I missed the \ in Log.

So:

1. It's the code inside the catch that is throwing the error that goes
   all the way to App:fatal
2. I could not replicate this again but write
   the exception through:

   ```
   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::error('message'.$exception);
   ```

   in App::fatal worked when I was
   debugging in different circumstances.
3. With the above line in the App::fatal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of following code:

```
try{
    $model->save();
}catch(\Exception $e){
    Log::info('Exception thrown');
}
```

Try this:

```
if(!$model->save()) {
    throw new Exception("Couldn't save!");
}
else {
    // success
}
```

By default there is (create if not) an exception handler in your `app/start/global.php`, like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    //Log::error($exception->getMessage());
});
```

You may also create a custom exception class by extending the base `Exception` class and can throw that custom exception instead.

**Update:** You are saving `$model->save();` instead of `$new->save();`.

> Why didn't it got caught in my catch

It's because a fatal error has occurred and you have a registered handler for fatal errors like one given below and error caught by that handler instead:

```
App::fatal(function($exception){
    //...
    return Response::json(...);
});
```

So, once you send the response from any error handler then it stops propagating to up, just finished the propagating with response sent.

Comment: Can you explain why the second code is better? I'm a newbie coming from Java, if an Exception is propagated all the way to App:fatal shouldn't it be caught by the try/catch?

Comment: Yes, if that is propagated then it'll go to the topmost one but it's also clean way to make two different decisions depending on the result, so if it succeeded then you may show the list of all models (index) or otherwise you may redirect back with errors and with old input.

Comment: Why didn't it got caught in my catch?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to save the wrong variable. Shouldn't save $new?

Here's how I do:

```
$reg = new Area;

$reg->name          = $name;
$reg->created_at    = time();
$reg->created_by    = Auth::user()->id;

$reg->save();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Don't know how I didn't catch that. But my original question remains - why just got caught at App::fatal? and the $exception variable there was empty. No explanations. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean. Can you explain a little more about the error?

Comment: What I don't understand is how Exceptions are propagated. The line $model->save() is the problem; it's inside the most generic try catch possible but it's not caught there. It propagates all the way to App::fatal. Right?

Comment: Yes, should be caught there. I think the better way to show the error is:


`try {   

} catch (Exception $e) {
   
     $this->message = $e->getMessage();
}`

Comment: The difference between your snippet and my code is my extra \ behind catch (Exception . Is that enough for the exception not be caught?

Comment: Test `throw new Exception ('Oops! Some Exception');` on the middle of try block to se if caught.